# How to append text to c3.js Regions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3.js

How Can I `append text to c3.js regions?` I have `three regions` in my chart and I would like to `append three different texts` to them. So far I have tried to use d3.js but with no success

```
var rectOffset = (( d3.select(this).attr("x") ) * 1) + 25;


d3.selectAll(".c3-region-0 rect")
.append("text")
.text("Some Text")
.attr("dy","15px")
.attr("dx",rectOffset+"px")
```

I get an error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
    at Array.d3_selectionPrototype.attr (d3.js:578)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrzxj3x2/34/)

code:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
         bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
      x: 'x',
        columns: [
        ["x", "2016-01-04", "2016-01-05", "2016-01-06", "2016-01-07", "2016-01-08", "2016-01-09", "2016-01-10", "2016-01-11", "2016-01-12", "2016-01-13", "2016-01-14", "2016-01-15", "2016-01-16", "2016-01-17", "2016-01-18", "2016-01-19", "2016-01-20", "2016-01-21", "2016-01-22", "2016-01-23", "2016-01-24", "2016-01-25", "2016-01-26", "2016-01-27", "2016-01-28", "2016-01-29", "2016-01-30", "2016-01-31", "2016-02-01", "2016-02-02", "2016-02-03"],
         ["Democrates", 49.85, 49.89, 49.82, 49.51, 49.42, 49.33, 49.24, 49.64, 49.57, 49.57, 49.01, 48.67, 48.7, 48.7, 48.7, 48.63, 48.63, 48.63, 48.63, 48.63, 48.61, 48.61, 48.68, 48.76, 48.84, 48.73, 48.76, 48.79, 48.81, 49.68, 49.63],
         ["Republicans", "50.15", "50.11", "50.18", "50.49", "50.58", "50.67", "50.76", "50.36", "50.43", "50.43", "50.99", "51.33", "51.30", "51.30", "51.30", "51.37", "51.37", "51.37", "51.37", "51.37", "51.39", "51.39", "51.32", "51.24", "51.16", "51.27", "51.24", "51.21", "51.19", "50.32", "50.37"]
        ],
         colors: {
            Democrates: '#4575b4',
            Republicans: '#d73027'
        },
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
             max: '2016-11-08',
            tick: {
               values: ["2016-02-01", "2016-06-14", "2016-11-08", "2016-09-26", "2016-10-19", "2016-07-18", "2016-07-28" ],
                format: function (x) {
                  if (x == "Mon Feb 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)"){
                  return 'Feb 01' + 'Primaries and Caucuses '
                } else if (x == "Tue Nov 08 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)") {
                   return 'Nov 08 Election Day'

                } else if (x == "Mon Sep 26 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)") {
                   return ' Sep 26 Start of Presidential Debates'

                } else if (x == "Mon Jul 18 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)") {
                   return 'Jul 25 Announcement of Nominees'

                } else {
                  var format=  d3.time.format("%b %d");
                                var date = format(x)
                                return date
                }},
                fit: false
        }
        }
    },
    grid: {
     y: {
        lines: [
                {value: 50},

            ]
     },
     x: {
    lines: [
      {value: "2016-01-08", text: "Want to rorate this text in 180 degrees",
      class: "xLineLable", position: "end"}


    ]
  }

  },
  regions: [

        {axis: 'x', start: "2016-02-01", end: "2016-06-14", class: 'regionX'},
        {axis: 'x', start: "2016-07-18", end: "2016-07-28", class: 'regionX'},
        {axis: 'x', start: "2016-09-26", end: "2016-10-19", class: 'regionX'}

    ]
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add text to a rect, you'll need to add it as a sibling element under the c3-region group element, which is a bit of a pain in d3 (and rectoffset needs to be a function, or the d3.select(this) gets the top-level dom node). In rectOffset I select the text's parentNode, then grab it's rect child node.

There were a couple of other gotchas that stopped the text turning up that I didn't expect.. attr always returns a string so .attr(x)+25 would return "75"+25 -> 7525, needed to cast to a number with '+'... I ended up using text-anchor instead anyways. Plus the fill-opacity needed to be adjusted for the text to be seen even when in the right spot. That had me flummoxed for a while.

```
var rectOffset = function () { return +d3.select(this.parentNode).select("rect").attr("x"); };


d3.selectAll(".c3-region-0")
.append("text")
.text("Some Text")
.attr("dy","15")
.attr("dx",rectOffset)
.style("fill-opacity", 1)
.attr("text-anchor", "start")
;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yrzxj3x2/35/